# Let A be a point inside a regular polygon of 10 sides. Let $P_1, P_2,\ldots, P_{10} $ be the distances of A from the sides of the polygon.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Let $A$ be a point inside a regular polygon of 10 sides. Let $P_1, P_2,\ldots, P_{10} $ be the distances of $A$ from the sides of the polygon. If each side is of length $2$ units, then find the value of $ P_ı + P_2 + \cdots + P_{10}$

I find out the area of the figure $ 10 \cot \frac \pi{10} $ . I found the question to be tough. Have no idea to do after that.

Comment: Hint: $P_k = \frac12 (P_k)(2)$ is the area of the triangle with apex at $A$ and base at edge $k$.

Comment: @achillehui why I can't accept your comment as answer!!!